# Cropping and tiling a background image with CSS

Tags: css, css-sprites

I have a CSS sprite image, `footer1.png`. I'd like to use CSS to crop out a section of the image, then tile the image as the background of my `.headimg3` element.

I'm trying to use the `clip` and `background` properties to achieve this, but the image isn't be cropped.

```css
.headimg3 {
  background: url(footer1.png) bottom;
  background-position: -35px -358px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height:34px;
  overflow: hidden; 
  clip: rect(0px, 200px, 0px, 400px); 
}
.headimgp {
  padding: 8px 0px 0px 10px;
  text-shadow: 2px 1px #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="headimg3">
  <div class="headimgp">
    &nbsp; LATEST Updates
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I crop and tile a background image using only CSS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The CSS `clip` property needs to have a `position` of `absolute` in order to function correctly.

```
.headimg3{
  background:url(footer1.png) bottom;
  background-position: -35px -358px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 34px;
  overflow: hidden; 
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0px, 200px, 0px, 400px); 
}
```

**Reference:** [**CSS Clip Property and Demo**](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/5-simple-but-useful-css-properties)

**Note:**
You can't use a section of any sprite image and have that section repeated because
 `background-repeat` is for ***the whole image***.

In this case use a [**image editor**](http://pixlr.com/editor/) and crop out the sprite you need and save it as a separate image file.